# .htaccess 404 pages not showing

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have one website, for that only error page is displaying for the main url.
e.g.: 404 error page is displayed in `www.example.com/123`.

When I go any other pages e.g.: `www.example.com/about.php/123`, the error page is not displayed. Only the same page without style sheet is displayed.

Here's my htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f``
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
ErrorDocument 404  http://www.example.com/404.php
```

Please help me to redirect to 404 pages when someone type wrong urls for the pages with the php extension (eg: `index.php`, `about.php`, `contact.php` etc)

Comment: what is the problem? when you enter `www.example.com/about.php/123` the `www.example.com/about.php` will be shown and about the stylesheet and other links. please give some examples or please give the site link.

Comment: the following is the my website url www.lizinfotech.com                                                  when i type   www.lizinfotech.com/123   404 page is displaying.     but when i go contact page http://www.lizinfotech.com/contactus.php/123  error page is not displaying

Comment: ?? I think you should edit your comment because I can't see any link.

Comment: http://www.lizinfotech.com  this is my website url when I type http://www.lizinfotech.com/123 the error page is displaying . but when I go any inner page  http://www.lizinfotech.com/contactus.php/123 the error page is not displaying.Instead the same contact page without style sheet is displaying.

Answer (score 0):

You try this code as per your page name and need some changes in " .htaccess " file.

```
**RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_-]+)$ index.php?action=$1 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)$ index.php?action=$1&mode=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9]+)$ index.php?action=$1&mode=$2&id=$3**
```

I hope solve the your problem.

Comment: Thanks Hardic for your suggestions..I have tried your code in .htaccess file,but still index page and other pages are not redirecting to 404 error page.

Comment: Thanks $Hardic patel for your suggestions..I have tried your code in .htaccess file,but still index page and other pages are not redirecting to 404 error page.any files in my server is not redirecting to 404 pages.only main url http://www.lizinfotech.com/123 is redirecting..Please check it.i am waiting for good soggestions..Thanks in advance